# inro sql question

Tags: sql

We are starting to do subqueries, and I have a bit of a toughie(for me, anyways).
We have a customers table, which has an attribute of creditLimit.  We have an orders table that has an ordernum, orderdate,quantity, amount.  We need to increase the credit limit of  a customer who has an order that exceeds their credit limit.  Then, take that customer and UPDATE his credit limit plus 1000.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming there is a primary-foreign key relationship between the Customers and Orders table.

```
UPDATE Customers SET Customers.creditLimit = Customers.creditLimit + 1000
    WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE Orders.Amount > Customers.creditLimit 
      AND Orders.CustomerNumber = Customers.CustomerNumber
    )
```